# Search for an algebraic proof of a near q-Vandermonde identity.

Tags: generating-functions, q-analogs, q-series

When trying to prove *[this q-binomial identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4673787)* I had soon the idea that here we have a *[q-Vandermonde identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Vandermonde_identity)* in disguise. I could transform the identity to

> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{(-1)^mq^{\binom{m+1}{2}+mn}
> \sum_{j=0}^m\binom{n}{j}_q\binom{-n-1}{m-j}_qq^{j(j-m-n)}=1}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
> for non-negative integers $n\leq m$. The identity (1) looks similar to the following q-Vandermonde identity:
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{j=0}^m&\binom{n}{j}_q\binom{-n-1}{m-j}_qq^{j(j-m-n-1)}
> =\binom{-1}{m}_q=(-1)^mq^{-\binom{m+1}{2}}\tag{2.1}
> \end{align*}
> from which
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{(-1)^mq^{\binom{m+1}{2}}\sum_{j=0}^m\binom{n}{j}_q\binom{-n-1}{m-j}_qq^{j(j-m-n-1)}=1}\tag{2.2}
> \end{align*}
> follows.

In (2.1) we use besides the q-Vandermonde identity
\begin{align*}
\binom{n+m}{t}_q=\sum_{j=0}^t\binom{n}{j}_q\binom{m}{t-j}_qq^{j(m-t+j)}
\end{align*}
the identity
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\binom{-n}{k}_q}
&=\frac{\left(1-q^{-n}\right)\left(1-q^{-n-1}\right)\cdots\left(1-q^{-n-k+1}\right)}
{\left(1-q\right)\left(1-q^2\right)\cdots\left(1-q^k\right)}\\
&=\left(\prod_{j=n}^{n+k-1}q^{-j}\right)(-1)^k
\frac{\left(1-q^{n}\right)\left(1-q^{n+1}\right)\cdots\left(1-q^{n+k-1}\right)}
{\left(1-q\right)\left(1-q^2\right)\cdots\left(1-q^k\right)}\\
&=q^{-\sum_{j=n}^{n+k-1}j}(-1)^k\binom{n+k-1}{k}_q\\
&=q^{-\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}(j+n)}(-1)^k\binom{n+k-1}{k}_q\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=q^{-nk-\binom{k}{2}}(-1)^k\binom{n+k-1}{k}_q}
\end{align*}

**Question:** How can we algebraically derive identity (1)? It seems that (2.2) could be helpful.

Comment: I believe that using the generalized q-binomial theorem carefully leads to an answer. I will write the required proof soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want to prove equation $(1)$, which is $$
(-1)^mq^{\binom{m+1}{2}+mn}\sum_{j=0}^m \binom{n}{j}_q\binom{-n-1}{m-j}_q q^{j(j-m-n)}=1
$$
It is sufficient to prove this with $q$ replaced by $q^{-1}$, in which case it is sufficient to prove that $$
\sum_{j=0}^m \binom{n}{j}_{q^{-1}}\binom{-n-1}{m-j}_{q^{-1}} q^{j(m+n-j)-mn}=(-1)^m q^{\binom{m+1}{2}}
$$
which is equivalent to $$
\sum_{j=0}^m \binom{n}{j}_{q^{-1}}\binom{-n-1}{m-j}_{q^{-1}}q^{-(j-m)(j-n) - \binom{m+1}{2}} = (-1)^m
$$

Note that $$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^kt^k = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-t)^k = \frac 1{1+t}
$$

Therefore, the coefficient of $t^m$ in $\frac 1{1+t}$ is $(-1)^m$. On the other hand, $$
\frac{1}{1+t} = \prod_{i=0}^{n-1} (1+q^{-i}(q^{-1}t)) \prod_{i=0}^{n} \frac 1{1+q^{-i}t} 
$$
The RHS is evaluable by the $q$-binomial theorem :$$
\prod_{i=0}^{n-1} (1+q^{-i}(q^{-1}t)) = \sum_{i=0}^n q^{-\binom{i+1}{2}}\binom{n}{i}_{q^{-1}}t^i = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} q^{-\binom{i+1}{2}}\binom{n}{i}_{q^{-1}}t^i
$$
and the associated identity the inverse of such a polynomial, which can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_binomial_coefficient) : $$
\prod_{i=0}^n \frac 1{1+q^{-i}t} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{n+k}{k}_{q^{-1}}(-1)^kt^k = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{-n-1}{k}_{q^{-1}}q^{-nk-\binom{k+1}{2}}t^k
$$
We used the same identity as the OP to convert the $q$-binomial coefficient into one with a negative top part. Hence, the associated coefficient of $t^m$ is formed by taking all $j=0$ to $m$ in the first term's expansion, and then letting $k=m-j$ in the second term's expansion. This yields $$
\sum_{j=0}^m \binom{-n-1}{m-j}_{q^{-1}}q^{-n(m-j)-\binom{m-j+1}{2}}q^{-\binom{j+1}{2}}\binom{n}{j}_{q^{-1}}\\
= \sum_{j=0}^m \binom{-n-1}{m-j}_{q^{-1}}\binom{n}{j}_{q^{-1}}q^{-(j-m)(j-n)-\binom{m+1}{2}}
$$

as desired.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranlyer: Many thanks for this great answer! (+1) I appreciate the representation of $\frac{1}{1+t}$ which cleverly enables us to use the q-binomial theorem. I will go through the details after work and accept it afterwards. KR

Comment: @epi163sqrt Thank you. Perhaps the main step was the recognition that I needed to use $q^{-1}$ in place of $q$. I actually used a similar argument and equality without replacing $q$. The identity which that give told me that somewhere, $q \to q^{-1}$ was the right thing to do, and voila, things are good.